# Generate method if not existent

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods, proxy

**Context**

I have a C# class [PyroProxy](https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite/blob/master/dotnet/Pyrolite/Pyro/PyroProxy.cs) with a `call(string method, params object[] arguments)` method

```
public class PyroProxy : IDisposable {

    public object call(string method, params object[] arguments)
}
```

This is the class of proxis to a remote objects.

**Motivation**

Using the call method all the time does not look nice in the code.

**Question**

Suppose the PyroProxy class has no method `test_method()`.
How can I make the following code work?

```
PyroProxy p = new PyroProxy();
p.test_method();
```

The code of the `test_method` looks like

```
public object test_method(params object[] arguments) {
    return call("test_method", arguments); // you get the point
}
```

This might be a duplicate I did not find, maybe it is possible during compile-time or run-time. What can I do to come closer to this goal? Hints are appreciated. There are answers about how to inject methods. I found the [ExpandoObject](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/02/adding-properties-and-methods-to-an-expandoobject-dynamicly/) but it does not tell me how to create unknown methods.

Comment: Are you wanting to add these methods at runtime?

Comment: Didn't the link you gave actually describe what you have to do?

`dictionary.Add("Shout", new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hellooo!!!"); })); person.Shout();`

Comment: @private_meta That means you have to set it before you call it. dcastro's answer doesn't need that.

Comment: @DavidG I want these methods to be present at run-time. I do not care when they are added.

Comment: Have you considered using a `DynamicProxy`? The problem with things like `Dynamic` is to to get the magic behavior you have to actually have to invoke them while being dynamic themselves. If you declare all the members you want to override virtual then a proxy class could be made that simply calls the call method and returns the result. Try castle DynamicProxy as it was fairly good at that purpose. It's slightly slow, but being as you are proxying a remoting call it makes zero difference.

Comment: @MichaelB I do not understand what you are writing about. Can you add some links and make your comment an answer? I am new to C# but not to programming. Where do I get that "DynamicProxy" from?

Comment: I was recommending something like http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/, the idea is you have your  class that you want to proxy declare all its members virtual. You build an interceptor, all it does it use the proxy to call the classes `call` method passing the method's name. You use castle's tool to generate an inheriting class using the interceptor. The proxy overrides all your members, and adds a call to the interceptor. The benefit over using dynamic is you can use this proxied class without having to declare it as dynamic, thus nice safe typesafe code.

Comment: Thanks, I will search my way through this. It looks promising. I will post an answer if you do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should derive from [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then override the [`TryInvokeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvokemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
public class PyroProxy : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(binder.Name + " was invoked");
        result = call(binder.Name, args);
        return true;
    }
}

dynamic proxy = new PyroProxy();
proxy.SomeMethod(); //prints "SomeMethod was invoked"
```

Comment: I chose this solution, although not implemented, because it captures the dynamic nature of the language the proxies go to. It would also allow to transform `getWidth()` to `get_width()` if required, to allow language styles to be unbroken. [Here](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/ping/) is the project we would have used it for.

Comment: Your proposal found its way into the [code of Pyrolite](https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite/blob/master/dotnet/Pyrolite/Pyro/PyroProxy.cs#L24). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)?

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static object test_method(this PyroProxy proxy, params object[] arguments)
    {
        return proxy.call("test_method", arguments); // you get the point
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this more than "automatic proxy generation", this allows you to keep track of which methods are actually used by your application, and prevents typos to ruin your day.

Comment: Can I do something like `public static class ExtensionMethods : DynamicObject`? I am just curious.

Comment: No, an extension method just pretends the method to belong to the class after the `this` keyword. The class containing it must be static, so not usable I think in your scenario.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Agree. Unless I miss something in the question, this answer looks much better to me than the one that uses `dynamic`. No typos error everywhere in the code, the only place method names are hardcoded is in a single static class.

Comment: @User: Any thoughts on your problem and the proposed solutions?

Comment: Yes, both are equally valid. I will evaluate them and come back after I have implemented something.